# Calculating Pandas Column from Prior Row's Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame of order start times and expected completion times for each order across different days.

I'd like to calculate a column that calculates the completion time for each order but updates the Order Start Time to be prior order's completion time if it is completed later than the original Order Start Time. Also, I'd like this calculation to be segmented across days (that is, the first order of the day doesn't depend on the completion time of the last order from the prior day).

```
data = {'Date': ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02'],
        'Order Start Time': ['2022-12-01 10:50:00.000', '2022-12-01 10:53:33.721', '2022-12-01 10:58:14.217', '2022-12-01 10:58:57.162', 
                             '2022-12-02 10:50:00.000', '2022-12-02 10:53:33.721', '2022-12-02 10:58:14.217', '2022-12-02 10:58:57.162'],
        'Order Rank Within Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Expected Completion Time': [125, 153, 75, 99, 165, 133, 85, 129]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Order Start Time', 'Order Rank Within Day', 'Expected Completion Time'])
```

The code I have is:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
  df['completion_time'] = np.where(df['Order Rank Within Day']==1, pd.to_datetime(df['Order Start Time']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Expected Completion Time'], unit='s'), df['completion_time'].at[row.Index-1])
```

But I get a KeyError. Is there a suggested solution?

Comment: `df['Order Rank Within Day']` is a series (a column so to speak). It cannot be equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. Changed to a np.where proposed solution.